# What's the type syntax for nested delegates?

Tags: syntax, d

I'm having trouble understanding how to express a nested delegate type in d syntax.

For example, how do I express these types?

- `a -> (b -> c)`
- `(a -> b) -> c`
- `a -> ((a -> b) -> b)`

where `a -> b` denotes a function taking one argument of type `a` and returning an argument of type `b`, and parentheses denote grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these correspond to your examples:

```
// a -> (b -> c)

alias t1 = C delegate(B) delegate(A);

// (a -> b) -> c

alias t2 = C delegate(B delegate(A));

// a -> ((a -> b) -> b)

alias t3 = B delegate(B delegate(A)) delegate(A);
```

Comment: Another point of confusion: `delegate b (a)` is the syntax for creating a value of type `b delegate (a)` or `(a -> b)`, so when declaring a delegate that accepts and returns delegates, those `delegate` keywords are still in the middle.